# Flatpickr range custom format

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I have a Flatpickr date input where I pass option range and it works fine. But upon selecting a date range the value en the input is shown as `03-02-2021 to 05-02-2021`. I would like to display it like `03 - 05 February 2021` How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works.. but may need to change the format (if diff months)

```
flatpickr(".has-datepicker", {
   mode: 'range',
   onChange: function (selectedDates, datestr) {
     $("#dateInput").val(selectedDates[0].getDay() + ' - ' + this.formatDate(selectedDates[0], "j F Y"));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, This bro

```
flatpickr(".dateRanger",{
    mode:"range",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    defaultDate: ["today", "today"],
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        instance.element.value = dateStr.replace('to', ',');
    },      
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).